# Replication and merge data back to the publisher on AlwaysOn Group SQL Server 2014

Tags: replication, sql-server-2014

My requirement is : Prod DB is on AlwaysOn Group with SQL Servre 2014.

I want to run CPU intensive jobs on replicated server and merge data back to the publisher.

Replicated DB required almost real time data (1-5 mins back data is fine) to run my jobs.

Which is the best Replication method for this scenario? Merge replication or Updatable Subscription Transaction replication.

And what is the overhead on Prod server?

Other technology options are in my mind are:

- SSIS ETL
- Async Framework